# Expresso Store Dynamic Price

Tags: expresso-store

I am trying to set up the dynamic price feature in Expresso Store. I have set the dynamic price setting to 'yes' for my channel field but the product form in my template does not display unless I set a price for the product.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a bug or not but you can enter `.` or `0` into the price field then in your template you would need to do something along the lines of:

```
{if price_val == 0}
  Price: <input type="text" name="price" value="" >
  <input type="hidden" id="item_qty" name="item_qty" value="1" />
{if:else}
  {price}
  <input type="text" id="item_qty" name="item_qty" value="{min_order_qty}" />
{/if}
```

Ideally you would have any item where a user can enter their own price in a particulate channel since it could allow technically savvy users to adjust the price of items where you have set the price. In that case you could then use a conditional on the channel instead of relying on the price for the conditional.

```
{if channel == "donations"}
  Price: <input type="text" name="price" value="" >
  <input type="hidden" id="item_qty" name="item_qty" value="1" />
{if:else}
  Your normal markup
{/if}
```

Comment: Seems to work without the conditional & just using a price of 0.

Comment: You only need the conditional if you have products that are not user defined prices. That way the user can not adjust the price of items where you have set the price.